# Interstitial ad on start of App

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I'd like to know how to add an interstitial ad on the start of my iOS app, written in Swift.
I have searched the whole web but only found answers in Objective C (which I'm not able to use with Swift) and for Android.

Is there any chance to get (i'd like to use iAds) advertising opens in fullscreen only when the user starts the app?

Why does Apple say it's only available for iPad?

Answer (score 1):

I have a code that I used before. Its written in swift. You can use it in wherever you want. First it checks for iAd, if it fails it will show admit banner. You may remove admit related parts if you don't want.

```
class AdHelper: NSObject {

private var iterationsTillPresentAd = 0 // Can be used to show an ad only after a fixed number of iterations
private var adMobKey = "ca-app-pub-3841570660522725/9161546495" // Stores the key provided by google
private var counter = 0
private var adMobInterstitial: GADInterstitial!


// Initialize iAd and AdMob interstitials ads
init(presentingViewController: UIViewController, googleAdMobKey: String, iterationsTillPresentInterstitialAd: Int) {
    self.iterationsTillPresentAd = iterationsTillPresentInterstitialAd
    self.adMobKey = googleAdMobKey
    self.adMobInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: self.adMobKey)
    presentingViewController.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual
}

// Present the interstitial ads
func showAds(presentingViewController: UIViewController) {

    // Check if ad should be shown
    counter++
    if counter >= iterationsTillPresentAd {

        // Try if iAd ad is available
        if presentingViewController.requestInterstitialAdPresentation() {
            counter = 0
            presentingViewController.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.None
            // The ad was used. Prefetch the next one
            preloadIAdInterstitial(presentingViewController)

            // Try if the AdMob is available
        } else {
            if adMobInterstitial == nil {
                // In case the disableAd was called
                adMobInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: self.adMobKey)
            } else {
                // Present the AdMob ad, if available
                if (self.adMobInterstitial.isReady) {
                    counter = 0
                    adMobInterstitial!.presentFromRootViewController(presentingViewController)
                    adMobInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: self.adMobKey)
                }
            }
            // Prefetch the next ads
            preloadIAdInterstitial(presentingViewController)
            preloadAdMobInterstitial()
        }
    }
}

// Disable ads
func disableAd(presentingViewController: UIViewController) {
    presentingViewController.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.None
    adMobInterstitial = nil
}

// Prefetch AdMob ads
private func preloadAdMobInterstitial() {
    var request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = ["kGADSimulatorID"] // Needed to show Ads in the simulator
    self.adMobInterstitial.loadRequest(request)
}

// Prefetch iAd ads
private func preloadIAdInterstitial(presentingViewController: UIViewController) {
    presentingViewController.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Manual
    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()
}
```

}

**Call the function where do you want(possible before view did load in your case):**

```
adHelper.showAds(self)
```